# TypeScript syntax error when importing

Tags: angular, typescript, tsc

I'm trying to learn TypeScript and Angular, but there's a strange error that keeps bugging me.

In short, I import a class named Point from the module point. The error suggests that a curly brace is wrong. The error points to the import statement in main.ts (line number 1).

Furthermore, I have the .ts and .js files in a folder. This folder does not have a tsconfig.json file.

I transpile and run the code with:

```
tsc main.ts --target ES2016 && node main.js
```

I target ES2016 for the support of getter and setter properties.

**error**

```
main.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Point } from './point';

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:238:19)
```

**main.ts**

```
import { Point } from './point';

let point = new Point(1);
point.draw();
let x = point.x;
console.log(x);
point.y = 500;
point.draw();
```

**point.ts**

```
export class Point {
    constructor(private _x?: number, private _y?: number) { }

    get x() {
        return this._x;
    }

    set y(value) {
        if (value < 0)
            throw new Error('New X must be 0 or higher.');

        this._y = value
    }

    draw() {
        console.log('X: ' + this._x + ', Y: ' + this._y);
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the error message? what you linked seems to be a bit of the transpiled code? Most likely since you are using modules you will need to get a module loader as well to run the code, you can't run it without.

Comment: actually I take that back, on node it should run I guess but the transpilation looks weird. Maybe you need to set module type in tsconfig.json to node instead of what you have now.

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot the actual error message. See my post above

Comment: In the console, also an arrow is pointing to the { in: import { Point

Comment: I think there is something wrong in the way you transpil typescript. Are you using webpack?

Comment: tsc main.ts --target ES2016 working fine

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmawi, indeed, transpiling does not produce errors, only when running the program in node with: node main.js

Comment: @CristianTraìna How can I find this out? I essentially use the compiler without modifying the configuration.

Comment: can you post the contents of your tsconfig.json?

Comment: @toskv, I don't have a tsconfig.json file, actually... Only main.ts, main.js, point.ts, and point.js in that folder

Comment: @toskv I now initialized tsc with tsc --init. This is my tsconfig.json file: {
  "compilerOptions": { "target": "ES2016", "module": "commonjs", "strict": true, "esModuleInterop": true     }}

Comment: @Tim it is related to node version, you have to use to run with --harmony  flag

Answer (score 3):

this `tsconfig.json` option.

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dest",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

and I have compile like this `tsc --p tsconfig.json` and everything seem working fine.

[image: typescript compile]

> typescript version : Version 2.9.2 
>   node version : v10.2.0